# ¿Como soluciono Undefined variable y problemas de ello en PHP?

Tags: mysqli

Estaba intentando crear una página web en PHP para un proyecto todo iba bien cuando lo guardé el problema fue cuando fui a la página y me apareció esto:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $personal in C:\xampp\htdocs\1514dmcr\Conexion.php on line 16
Warning: Undefined variable $horario in C:\xampp\htdocs\1514dmcr\Conexion.php on line 16
Warning: Undefined variable $fecha in C:\xampp\htdocs\1514dmcr\Conexion.php on line 16
Warning: Undefined variable $materiales in C:\xampp\htdocs\1514dmcr\Conexion.php on line 16
Warning: Undefined variable $zona in C:\xampp\htdocs\1514dmcr\Conexion.php on line 16
```

[image: Aquí le dejo los códigos]

Comment: Una de las cosas es que defines las variables con la primera letra mayúscula, y luego en la sentencia sql intentas utilizarla con minúscula. Por eso no están definidas (PHP es case-sensitive). Revisa tus variables.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

En concreto el problema se soluciona definiendo la variable antes de usarla.

Muchas veces es un error de dedo; en tu código declaras las variables usando *Pascal case* pero cuando las llamas estás escribiendo en minúsculas.

Recomiendo que busques un estilo de formateo de código y te apegues a él para evitar estos errores en el futuro; por ejemplo:

- **snake_case** para variables
- **PascalCase** para clases, interfaces y traits
- **camelCase** para funciones
- **kebab-case** para saber que existe (no se puede usar en PHP)

Con el pasar del tiempo estarás acostumbrada a escribir todas tus variables de la misma manera  y evitarás este tipo de problemas.